# Problem in citation link in Google scholar

Tags: google-scholar

I have uploaded a paper in [eprint site](https://eprint.iacr.org/). In my Google scholar, the citation  of my paper is addressed by the semanticscholar.org site.

My problem is that, I have revised my paper in eprint site, but in Google scholar, researchers can not access to this revision of paper, since semanticscholar.org did not update my paper to the new revision of paper. I contacted with the support system of semanticscholar.org, but after one month no change is happen. Moreover, when I search the title of paper in my Google scholar,   Google just present the semanticscholar link of my paper and dose not show its eprint link.

My Question: Is there a way to add the paper in my Google scholar with the its eprint link.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Google scholar indexes what it can crawl.  If it it already crawls and links to papers on that eprint site, it *should* eventually include yours.

Comment: @Kimball Although based on logic your comment is correct, it does not work in practice. In other words, as I mentioned in the question when I search the title of paper in my Google scholar, Google just present the semanticscholar link of my paper and dose not show its eprint link.

Comment: What I mean is it takes time, and the should is in italics because it is not 100% accurate.  Does Google Scholar have links to other papers on that eprint site?

Comment: @Kimball For example [this paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Constructing+Low-latency+Involutory+MDS+Matrices+with+Lightweight+Circuit&btnG=) is linked by Google Scholar  from eprint site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Scholar recommends](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html) to make publications available on a personal university webpage:

> If you're an individual author, it works best to simply upload your paper to your website, e.g., www.example.edu/~professor/jpdr2009.pdf; and add a link to it on your publications page, such as www.example.edu/~professor/publications.html.

Afaik, there is no way to request a particular repository or paper to be added/updated/deleted, the whole system is automatic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it dose not related with my question.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. So now I'm confused, your goal is not to update the version of your paper in Google Scholar database?

Comment: My goal is that I want to change the destination of the paper in my Google Scholar from semanticscholar.org to [eprint](https://eprint.iacr.org/) site such as [this paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Constructing+Low-latency+Involutory+MDS+Matrices+with+Lightweight+Circuit&btnG=). Thanks

Comment: Ok so maybe my answer wasn't clear, but it looks like I wasn't that far off: to the best of my knowledge what you are asking is impossible, I'm afraid. If Scholar doesn't collect the paper itself from eprint, you can only indirectly influence it by putting the new version somewhere else, and for that your best bet is probably to follow their advice. Maybe having a simple link to the eprints version on your webpage would also do the trick, I don't know. I'm guessing that If eprint was regularly crawled by the Google bot it's likely that it would have already found the new version.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to help me.